# Hibernate: @NotAudited and OneToMany mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

**@NotAudited** and **@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)** not working with OneToMany mapping on a join table. The Join table has an association with 2 different tables and one of them is Auditable. This is a legacy code and has both Annotation and XML-based configuration, Table A and C have XML configurations.

Mapping of Table A:

```
@Audited
Class A{
    int aid;
    @NotAudited
    List<B> b;
}
```

XML configuration of Table A:

```
<set name="b" table="B" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="all, delete-orphan" fetch="select">
   <key column="aid" not-null="true"/>
   <one-to-many class="B"/>
</set>
```

Mapping of Join Table B:

```
@Entity
Class B{
    @Id
    int bid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "aid", referencedColumnName = "aid")
    A a;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cid", referencedColumnName = "cid")
    C c;
}
```

Mapping of Table C:

```
Class C{
    int cid
    B b;
}
```

XML configuration of Table C:

```
<one-to-one name="b" property-ref="c" class="B" cascade="all"/>
```

I see the following message when the application is getting up.

```
An audited relation from A.b to a not audited entity B
```

If I put @Audited on Table B then I see query exception table B_aud does not exist.

How can I fix this?